# Work laptop (Ubuntu 18.04) in bootloop! Please help!

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04, bootloader

I've got a Purism Librem 13 ([hardware specs here](https://puri.sm/products/librem-13/#specs)) with Ubuntu 18.04 running on it fine for almost a year now. I've had a freeze once every couple months or so, but nothing too serious.

Yesterday it happened twice that my laptop suddenly rebooted out of nowhere and today it has big trouble starting up. I get to Grub and if I continue booting Ubuntu normally it does one of three things:

1. show a cursor, then a black screen, and then it reboots again
2. show a cursor, then a black screen and then nothing (have to long press power to power down and then hit power to start it again)
3. show a cursor, then a black screen, then some errors (see below) and then a black screen.

I've tried this about 30 times now. Most of the time it's either number 1 or two of the above, but I just managed to catch the errors it shows:

[image]

I really have no idea what these lines mean.

I ran a memtest (took an hour) and that ended with no errors. I'm now on kernel `4.15.0-45-generic` so I tried booting with the previous kernel `4.15.0-43-generic`, but that gives the same result.

I then tried booting in recovery mode. That works (writing in it now), but I'm not sure what to do from here. Most things are backed up fine, so I'm good there. I considered reinstalling Ubuntu, but I'm currently abroad and I don't have the possibility to reinstall Ubuntu now. And this is my work laptop and I need it again in the morning.

Does anybody know what I can do to debug or solve this? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
Since grub is loading, but it doesn't ask for the passphrase for my encrypted disk, I guess the problem lies within the Linux kernel. As said in [the news article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117135/work-laptop-ubuntu-18-04-in-bootloop-please-help?noredirect=1#comment1845435_1117135) posted in the comments by @pomsky, there was a regression in a kernel preventing Ubuntu 18.04 with certain chipsets to from booting. This sounds very much like my problem, but they say that Ubuntu 18.04 setups with kernel `4.18` are urged to update the kernel packages immediately, while I'm currently running kernel `4.15.0-45-generic`. I ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` but it says all packages are up to date. I also installed `ukuu` to install a newer kernel, but there are so many kernels that I'm not sure which version to pick.

Also, in the [Ubuntu kernel support schedule for Ubuntu 18.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=18.04.x%20Ubuntu%20Kernel%20Support%20Schedule.svg) I see no mention of kernel `4.18`. Only kernel `4.15` is mentioned.

Does anybody know what to do from here?

Comment: This is a bit of a longshot, but try setting a boot time kernel parameter "iommu=soft".  At boot time, where you have selected  prior kernels, edit the linux cmd line and where you see "quiet splash" change to "quiet splash iommu=soft".  If this helps, you can make the change permanent.

Comment: @CharlesGreen - I tried your suggestion, but the result is unfortunately the same. Any other ideas?

Comment: The only other one that I have would be to boot from a live USB and run `fsck` on your disks.

Comment: See this: https://news.softpedia.com/news/canonical-apologizes-for-another-ubuntu-linux-kernel-regression-fix-available-524892.shtml

Comment: @pomsky - Thanks for the link. That gives me hope it will be fixed. In the article it says: "If you're running Ubuntu 18.10 or Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Linux kernel 4.18, you are urged to update your kernel packages immediately". I checked (`uname -a`) but I'm running kernel version `4.15.0-45-generic`. I ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` but it says all packages are the latest. I also installed `ukuu` to install a newer kernel, but there are so many kernels that I'm not sure which version to pick. Would you have any further tips?